# List all possible strings from given possibilities for characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

Maybe it's too early in the morning for recursion, but I'm having an inordinate amount of trouble coming up with the right algorithm for this.

I have a string like this: `abcd`

Except that I'm not totally sure of all of its letters. It's possible that the `a` should actually be an `A` or maybe even an `@`. The `d` may be a `d` or it may be a `D` or even a `+`. So I have come up with this:

```
possibilities = [['a', 'A', '@'], 'bc', ['d', 'D', '+']]
```

I want to come up with a list of all the possible words that it could be:

```
output = [
    'abcd',
    'Abcd',
    '@bcd',
    'abcD',
    # etc.
]
```

The order of this list doesn't matter to me.

I took a look at [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), but from a glance, I couldn't find a function that suited me, so I decided to implement a recursive solution.

```
def find_possible_strings(possibilities):
  res = []
  f2(possibilities, '', res)
  return res

def f2(possibilities, s, final_result):
  for i,elem in enumerate(possibilities):
    if type(elem) == str:
      s += elem
    else:
      for e in elem:
        f2(possibilities[i+1:], s + e, final_result)

  final_result.append(s)

possibilities = [['a', 'A', '@'], 'bc', ['d', 'D', '+']]
print '\n'.join(find_possible_strings(possibilities))
```

Right now, it prints:

```
abcd
abcD
abc+
abc
Abcd
AbcD
Abc+
Abc
@bcd
@bcD
@bc+
@bc
bcd
bcD
bc+
bc
```

I believe I'm getting all the possible strings I want, but also a bunch of incomplete strings. The problem I think is that I'm not adding to the `s` in the `else` block, so the `s` I append at the end of the function is incomplete.

Barring throwing in a cheat like `if len(s) != 4: return` at the end of the function, how do I fix this function?

You can change the input and output data structures if another is more suitable. You can replace my function with a library call of course if that makes things simpler.

I'll tinker with this some more in the meantime.

Comment: This may not be what you want here, but what you’ve described is a very simple regular language that can easily be coded as a trivial regex like `[aA@]bc[dD+]`. Of course the re library doesn’t let you generate all of the strings that a pattern could match (and you wouldn’t ever want to do that for the full complexity of extended regex patterns), but a program to expand basic regular expressions without repeats is pretty easy to write and might be instructive to try writing.

Comment: Also, if you _did_ want to make this work recursively, just passing the partial strings back up would be simpler than building the strings in an accumulator downward. And that's true for the majority of recursive problems. It's worth knowing how to write accumulating tail recursion (especially if you want to use other languages that do tail call elimination, and that encourage tail recursion over looping), but it's often worth writing and testing the easier way first anyway. And, in Python, it's often worth stopping there, because without TCE, there's no real benefit to tail recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a recursion-shaped problem, so put down that hammer.

You are generating the *cartesian product* of 4 lists of possibilities, one for each position. Use `itertools.product()` (and give each position it's own list), and you are done:

```
from itertools import product

possibilities = [['a', 'A', '@'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d', 'D', '+']]

for combo in product(*possibilities):
    print(''.join(combo))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> possibilities = [['a', 'A', '@'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d', 'D', '+']]
>>> for combo in product(*possibilities):
...     print(''.join(combo))
...
abcd
abcD
abc+
Abcd
AbcD
Abc+
@bcd
@bcD
@bc+
```